# Format date as Year/Quarter

Tags: r, date

I have the following dataframe:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  date = c("2001-01-01", "2001-02-01", "2001-03-01", "2001-04-01", "2001-05-01", "2001-06-01"),
  qtr = c("NA", "NA","NA","NA","NA","NA")
)
```

I want to fill Data$qtr with Year/Quarter - f.e. 01/01 (I need this format!).

I wrote a function:

```
fun <- function(x) { 
  if(x == "2001-01-01" | x == "2001-02-01" | x == "2001-03-01") y <- "01/01"
  if(x == "2001-04-01" | x == "2001-05-01" | x == "2001-06-01") y <- "01/02"
  return(y)
}
n$qtr <- sapply(n$date, fun)
```

But it does not work. I always get the error message:

```
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : Object 'y' not found
```

Why?

Comment: You're probably getting that error because one of your dates isn't matched in either of the `if` expressions. So `y` was never assigned in `fun`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need to explicilty `Vectorize` your function:

```
fun_v <- Vectorize(fun, "x")
fun_v(Data$date)
#[1] "01/01" "01/01" "01/01" "01/02" "01/02" "01/02"
```

However, when it comes to more or less standard tasks (such as datetime manipulations), there's always a solution already available:

```
library(zoo)
yq <- as.yearqtr(Data$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
yq
#[1] "2001 Q1" "2001 Q1" "2001 Q1" "2001 Q2" "2001 Q2" "2001 Q2"
```

To convert to your specific format, use

```
format(yq, format = "%y/0%q")
#[1] "01/01" "01/01" "01/01" "01/02" "01/02" "01/02"
```

Comment: thank you. using "format(z, format="%y/0%q") would be perfect. but as a result I get "01/0q" and so on

Comment: You might have forgotten the `%` sign before `q`.

Answer (score 21):

I have been loving the `lubridate` package for working with dates. Super slick. The `quarter` function finds the quarter (of course) and then just pair that with the year.

```
library(lubridate)
Data <- Data %>%
  mutate(qtr = paste0(substring(year(date),3,4),"/0",quarter(date)))
```

If you are not familiar with the `%>%` from `magrittr` the first line basically says "use data frame called `Data`" and the second line says "mutate (or add) a column called `qtr`"

**EDIT 2021-Q2**

If the "YY/QQ" format is not critical, then a quick and safe way to get the year and the quarter is:

```
library(lubridate)
Data %>%
  mutate(qtr = quarter(date, with_year = T))
```

Comment: Or use with year argument: `quarter(x, with_year = TRUE)`

Answer (score 12):

Using base functions:

```
Data$date <- as.Date(Data$date)
Data$qtr <- paste(format(Data$date, "%y"), 
                  sprintf("%02i", (as.POSIXlt(Data$date)$mon) %/% 3L + 1L), 
                  sep="/")

#         date   qtr
# 1 2001-01-01 01/01
# 2 2001-02-01 01/01
# 3 2001-03-01 01/01
# 4 2001-04-01 01/02
# 5 2001-05-01 01/02
# 6 2001-06-01 01/02
```

Answer (score 7):

I made a similar format using `quarters()` and `sub()` in R:

```r
Data$qtr <- paste(format(Data$date, "%y/"), 0, 
                  sub( "Q", "", quarters(Data$date) ), sep = "")
```

Answer (score 7):

another option would be:

```
Data$qtr <- lubridate::quarter(Data$date, with_year = T)
```

Answer (score 2):

`tidyverse`'s [`clock`](https://clock.r-lib.org/index.html) gives an alternative, with the advantage of not loosing the original day, with `calendar_narrow` and [date precision](https://clock.r-lib.org/articles/motivations.html?q=variabl#variable-precision):

```r
library(clock)
library(dplyr)

#Function to convert a date to year-quarter
toQ <- . %>% 
  date_parse() %>% 
  as_year_quarter_day() %>% 
  calendar_narrow("quarter")

Data %>% 
  mutate(qtr = toQ(date))
```

output

```r
        date     qtr
1 2001-01-01 2001-Q1
2 2001-02-01 2001-Q1
3 2001-03-01 2001-Q1
4 2001-04-01 2001-Q2
5 2001-05-01 2001-Q2
6 2001-06-01 2001-Q2
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data.table` package and its `IDate` class have some nice convenience functions (e.g. `quarter()`, `year()`), similar to those of `lubridate` available. `paste0()` them together as you please.

```r
Data <- data.frame(
  date = c("2001-01-01", "2001-02-01", "2001-03-01",
           "2001-04-01", "2001-05-01", "2001-06-01")
)

require(data.table)
setDT(Data)

Data[ , date := as.IDate(date) ] # data.table s integer based date class
Data[ , qtr := paste0(year(date), '/', quarter(date)) ]
# your specific format
Data[ , qt2 := paste0(substr(year(date),3,4), '/', '0', quarter(date)) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another (longer) way
 of doing it using if statements is this:

```
month <- as.numeric(format(date, format = "%m"))[1]

if (month < 4) {
    quarter <- paste( format(date, format = "%Y")[1], "Q1", sep="-")
} else if (month > 3 & month < 7) {
    quarter <- paste( format(date, format = "%Y")[1], "Q2", sep="-")            
} else if (month > 6 & month < 10) {
    quarter <- paste( format(date, format = "%Y")[1], "Q3", sep="-")
} else if (month > 9) {
    quarter <- paste( format(date, format = "%Y")[1], "Q4", sep="-")
}
```

Returns a string in the format:

```
> quarter
[1] "2001-Q1"
```

Then you could extend that using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
yq=function(x,prefix="%Y",combine="Q") paste0(ifelse(is.null(prefix),"",format(x,"%Y")),floor(as.numeric(format(x,"%m"))/3-1e-3)+1,sep=combine)
```

this gives the flexibility of returning any format back that has the quarter in it

no need for chron or zoo

as for your example

```
yq(as.Date("2013-04-30"),prefix="%y",combine="/0")
> [1] "13/02"
```

Comment: With yearqtr you can easily add quarters and perform other manipulations and you can also plot yearqtr objects and have it come out correctly but not with character strings.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for a format such as 1Q21 for 1st quarter 21, I used @Roland answer above and made a small change towards:

```
paste(sprintf("%2i", (as.POSIXlt(Notional$Date)$mon) %/% 3L + 1L), format(Notional$Date, "%y"),sep="Q")
```