# Merging two time series with different time index formatting

Tags: r, time-series

I have two time series as showed below (the first measures consumption; the second GDP). The problem is that the time indexes are in a different format and they have different lengths (both goes all the way until the present; thus, GDP is longer).

What would be the best way to merge them two having as a result only three columns: TIME, CON, GDP? The indexes should also match correctly, i.e. 1965-01-01 is in the same row as 1965-Q1.

```
          DATE       CON
1   1965-01-01  60814.67
2   1965-04-01  61643.33
3   1965-07-01  62753.33
4   1965-10-01  63310.67
.      .          .
.      .          .
.      .          .
    2015-01-01  13908.03

        TIME     GDP
4364 1955-Q1 90872.2
4365 1955-Q2 93454.7
4366 1955-Q3 95558.2
4367 1955-Q4 94438.4
.      .          .
.      .          .
.      .          .
     2015-Q1 199872.4
```

Comment: What are the possible values for the date column? Could it contain any date or only the first day of the quarter?

Comment: Try this question to reformat the `DATE` column: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571703/format-date-as-year-quarter

Comment: @Micahel, the four last digits of the date are the same for all year, each one representing one quarter. Q1 = 01-01 ; Q2 = 04-01 and so on...

The only thing that changes is the year...

Comment: Perhaps you don't realize the dates in your example are from different decades?

Comment: @A. Webb, the data have different length. I've edited the example to make it clear that the series keep going until 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `merge` from `zoo`. Assuming the data is in `df1` and `df2`, and using the snips from 1955 and 1965 plus the addition from 2015...

```
library(zoo)

CON<-zoo(df1$CON,as.yearqtr(as.Date(df1$DATE)))
GDP<-zoo(df2$GDP,as.yearqtr(sub("-"," ",df2$TIME)))

merge(CON,GDP)
```

```
             CON      GDP
1955 Q1       NA  90872.2
1955 Q2       NA  93454.7
1955 Q3       NA  95558.2
1955 Q4       NA  94438.4
1965 Q1 60814.67       NA
1965 Q2 61643.33       NA
1965 Q3 62753.33       NA
1965 Q4 63310.67       NA
.              .        .
.              .        .
.              .        .
2015 Q1 13908.03 199872.4
```