# Aggregate Dates to produce unique periods

Tags: r, aggregate

I would like to able to aggregate survey data collected over a range of days into a unique period. For example, for the first three dates (2015-03-17, 2015-03-23, 2015-03-26), i'd like to combine to produce the period "March 2015". I will then use these combined dates to produce boxplots which show "Average.Counts" for that period.

All up I would like to make 4 unique periods:

- March 15 (first 3 dates as per table below)
- September 15 (dates 4,5 as per table below)
- March 2016 (dates 6-15 as per table below)
- September 2016 (dates 16-23 as per table below)

Here are the dataset headings.

```
head(Survival.Pre.Harvest)
Bay.Unique       Date Average.Count Total.Predators Time Previous.Average.Count
2          1 2015-03-17         346.9               2    0                     NA
3          1 2015-09-14         326.6               8  181                  346.9
4          1 2016-02-29         322.6               3  349                  326.6
7          2 2015-03-17         326.4               2    0                     NA
8          2 2015-09-14         288.8               4  181                  326.4
9          2 2016-02-29         271.4               6  349                  288.8
```

These are the unique dates within the dataset.

> table(Survival.Pre.Harvest$Date)

```
2015-03-17 2015-03-23 2015-03-26 2015-09-14 2015-09-15 2016-02-24 2016-02-25 2016-02-26 2016-02-29 
     9          3          1          9          3          4          6          6          5 
2016-03-01 2016-03-02 2016-03-03 2016-03-04 2016-03-22 2016-03-23 2016-09-12 2016-09-13 2016-09-14 
     3          6          3          6          6          2          6          6          4 
2016-09-20 2016-09-22 2016-10-18 2016-10-19 2016-10-20 
     7         10          4          3         14
```

Thanks in advance!

```
dput(head(Survival.Pre.Harvest))
structure(list(Bay.Unique = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), Date = structure(c(16511, 
16692, 16860, 16511, 16692, 16860), class = "Date"), Average.Count = c(346.9, 
326.6, 322.6, 326.4, 288.8, 271.4), Total.Predators = c(2L, 8L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 6L), Time = c(0, 181, 349, 0, 181, 349), Previous.Average.Count =    c(NA, 
346.9, 326.6, NA, 326.4, 288.8)), .Names = c("Bay.Unique", "Date", 
"Average.Count", "Total.Predators", "Time", "Previous.Average.Count"
), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571703/format-date-as-year-quarter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
Survival.Pre.Harvest$Date <- ymd(Survival.Pre.Harvest$Date)
bks = ymd("2015-01-01", "2015-08-31", "2016-01-01", "2016-08-31", "2017-01-01")
lbs <- c("Mar2015", "Sep2015", "Mar2016", "Sep2016")
Survival.Pre.Harvest$yearmonth <- cut.Date(Survival.Pre.Harvest$Date, breaks = bks, labels = lbs)
ggplot(Survival.Pre.Harvest, aes(x=yearmonth, y=Average.Count)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for the info. I do get an error when I run the second line of code: Error in df$yearmonth <- format(Survival.Pre.Harvest$Date, format = "%B%Y") : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
Any ideas?

Comment: Also there are multiple observations for each date (126 all up over the 23 various dates), so the boxplots will be okay. I have produced them for the unique dates, but it would be better to combine into periods. Thanks

Comment: Could you please edit your question adding your data using dput()?

Comment: Hi @ed_sans, I think it is something to do with the download of the lubridate package actually. After re-running, I get the following error: Error in x11() : X11 module cannot be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
running command ''otool' -L '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules/R_X11.so'' had status 1 
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

Comment: @Greeny, don't use x11(). It just open a new graphic device in Windows. I edited the answer

Comment: Thanks @ed_sans. I can't work out why I get this error.... Error in df$date <- format(Octopus.Survival.Pre.Harvest$Date, format = "%B%Y") : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: That works! Thanks very much. September 2016 and October 2016 are still separate, so not sure whether I can combine these. And is there a way to order the dates so they are sequential? At the moment the dates are in alphabetical order. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Greeny How do you want to group the months? e.g. Sept and Oct . Into semesters?

Comment: I would like to group them all as September 2016.

Comment: Yes, but you need to specify, how you group them. For example, Sept, Oct, Nov, labeled as Sept. And Jan, Feb and March as March. Are you using just March and Sept?

Comment: Yes that's correct, I just want to show four periods (two for each year). March 2015, Sept 2015, Mar 2015, Sept 2016.

Comment: See the edit above. Note that we use the cut() function with breaks and labels. Adjust accordingly. Hope it works

Comment: Fabulous! That's perfect. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it. It seems so simple now. This will definitely come in handy in the future. All the best :)