# Replace roman numerals and create a variable with year-quarter date

Tags: r, roman-numerals

I want to adjust a column to use it as a date variable in a chart. However the variable contains Roman numerals as month and on the other hand a year displayed in Arabic numerals.

```
 Factor w/ 34 levels "I-III 2010","I-III 2011",..
```

I'd like to transform these values into the following pattern (year-quarter ): 2010-1 , 2011-1.

I tried the following, but not sure if it's the best way to approach my problem.

```
df$var = gsub("I-III", "1 -", df$var)
df$var = gsub("IV-VI", "2 -", df$var)
df$var = gsub("VII-IX","3 -", df$var)
df$var = gsub("X-XII","4 -", df$var)
```

What would you recommend?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want `2010-1` when there are two roman numerals (1 and 3)

Comment: Presumable I-III == Jan-Mar == 1st quarter. @Kamil Sawczak Please show the pattern for all four quarters and what you have tried so far.

Comment: because it is showing a range from Jan to March what is actually a quarter 1

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571703/format-date-as-year-quarter

Comment: @Henrik I updated the discription

Comment: What's wrong with the way you do it already?