# When I try to make a new column in r for each date to indicate its quarter it only gives me one response

Tags: r, date

In one of my columns I am given a date. I am trying to make a new column to indicate which quarter that date lies in so that way i can determine how many observations entered a certain venue in each quarter. End goal is to sumarize based off of quarter. Here is an example of the code I am using and an example of the output. as.Date(as.yearqtr(x, format ="%Y-%m-%d" )) [image]. As you can see my problem is that It only returns 2019 q2, and i am confused why. This is my code PARTIES$QUARTER <- (as.yearqtr(PARTIES$opened, format = "%Y-%M-%d"))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format date as Year/Quarter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571703/format-date-as-year-quarter)

Answer (score 0):

It should be `%m` for (`month`) and not `%M` (which specifies the `Minute as decimal number (00–59).`)

```
library(zoo)
PARTIES$QUARTER <- as.yearqtr(PARTIES$opened, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: now its only giving me q2 and q3 ??

Comment: still missing q1 and q4

Comment: @aped based on the example, showed it iis q3, `as.yearqtr(c("2019-09-30", "2019-09-26", "2019-09-19"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")#
[1] "2019 Q3" "2019 Q3" "2019 Q3"`

Comment: do you know if it is possible to summarize how many entrys are in each month ?