# R filtering multiple Combinations

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

What is the most efficient/easiest way to filter for multiple combinations using filter?

Example- I want results returned for year 2022 and quarter 1, year 2021 and quarter 2, and so on... I don't think the below is the correct/best way at looking at it:

```
dataset %>%
filter(year== "2022" & quarter== "1") %>%
filter(year== "2021" & quarter== "4") %>%
filter(year== "2021" & quarter== "3") %>%
filter(year== "2021" & quarter== "2")
```

Comment: This will return nothing since you can't match >1 of these filters. You might use what you have but like `filter((year == "2022" & quarter == "1") | (year == "2021" & quarter == "2") | ...etc... )` where the `|` means "or". It will probably be simpler to convert the quarter into a numeric form so you can filter a range in a single step. This could be done a few ways, eg using the `zoo` package's `yearqtr` data type: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21572025/6851825. Or a simple version could be `mutate(yearqtr = as.numeric(paste0(year,quarter))) %>% filter(yearqtr >= 202102, year_qtr <= 20221)`

Comment: Could you clarify *"I want results returned for year 2022 and quarter 1, year 2021 and quarter 2, and so on... "* - do you want them summarized in the same data object? Do you want to be able to input a given year and quarter and see what values return? What do you want your final data to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you want to select a range of dates. If you combine year and quarter into a single value, you can easily filter on those.

**Example dataset**

```
df = data.frame(year = c("2000","2000","2000","2000","2001","2001","2001","2001"),
                quar = c("1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4")
                )
```

**Create combined field**

```
df <- df %>% mutate(period = paste(df$year, df$quar))

  year quar period
1 2000    1 2000 1
2 2000    2 2000 2
3 2000    3 2000 3
4 2000    4 2000 4
5 2001    1 2001 1
6 2001    2 2001 2
7 2001    3 2001 3
8 2001    4 2001 4
```

Make sure not to separate the values with a `.` or `-`, as R will process them as a decimal point or a minus. You could also just combine them into a single digit (20001, 20002, etc), but I think that would be less legible.

**Easy filtering**

For a range:

```
df %>% filter(period >= "2000 3" & period <= "2001 2")

  year quar period
1 2000    3 2000 3
2 2000    4 2000 4
3 2001    1 2001 1
4 2001    2 2001 2
```

For multiple individual values, use the OR operator `|`:

```
df %>% filter(period == "2000 1" | period == "2000 3")

  year quar period
1 2000    1 2000 1
2 2000    3 2000 3
```

And of course, the ORs `|` and ANDs `&` can all be combined. Keep in mind to use parentheses to define the order of operations:

```
df %>% filter(period == "2000 1" | (period >= "2000 3" & period <= "2001 2"))

  year quar period
1 2000    1 2000 1
2 2000    3 2000 3
3 2000    4 2000 4
4 2001    1 2001 1
5 2001    2 2001 2
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks everyone!! Was able to get the results I wanted. Thank you!